# not be able to read cell comment

Tags: php, phpexcel

I want to read comment written inside a cell in excel sheet but i am not be able to read it, following is my piece of code.

```
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
$objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load("first.xlsx");
$objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
objWorksheet->getComment('A2')->getText();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is

```
$objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);
```

which tells PHPExcel to read only the cell data, ignoring any formatting or comments, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Might it also be that you are trying to ()->getText() without defining a objTextReader ?????

I'm been able to get the comments with the setDataReadOnly(true);

Hope it helps