# php-excel-reader get cell comments

Tags: php, excel

I'm using:

http://code.google.com/p/php-excel-reader/

And I was wondering if it was possible, to get the cell comments? The documentation seems fairly limited.  Does anyone have any idea if it is implemented, or how to modify the class to implement it?

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

php-excel-reader doesn't read cell comments... comments are stored in the SPREADSHEET_EXCEL_READER_TYPE_NOTE block, but the reader simply skips these blocks.

If you want to modify php-excel-reader to read cell annotations such as notes, you'll need to create a reader block to handle that option in the switch block of the worksheet substream. Take a look at how [PHPExcel](http://www.phpexcel.net) reads cell comments to see what the logic should be (the code is in the /Classes/PHPExcel/Reader/Excel5.php file in the _readNote() method), or switch to a Excel library that can actually read cell annotations anyway.

Comment: Thanks, that helps alot actually.  I've found the switch that reads the cells, So i can just modify that now that I know which one it is.  Thank you!

Comment: Alright I'm having some trouble with this.  I cannot work out how this class works and I'm just going round in circles.  Any ideas?

Comment: If you're trying to fix Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader and have specific problems, then post the details in a new question and I'll try to help; but I'm not going to get involved in patching/resurrecting Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader. I have little enough time to develop PHPExcel; so reviving a dead project to duplicate functionality that I've already developed in PHPExcel is not at the top of my priority list. My advice would be to switch to using PHPExcel.

Answer (score 0):

Look at these post [not be able to read cell comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5276348/not-be-able-to-read-cell-comment)

it basically says you can get you're comments easily. with getComments() to get the all or getComment('A1') to get  a single one.

```
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load("first.xlsx");
$objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
objWorksheet->getComment('A2');
objWorksheet->getComments();
```